# The "Allow anyway" button on the "... was blocked from use because it is not from an identified developer" does not appear

Tags: macos

[image]

enter image description here
I have selected "App store an identified developers" in the security setting

there is supposed to be an "Allow Anyway" button that appears when I try to open the non-identified app.

However, this button does not appear. See the modal side-by-side with the setting from the settings panel

Answer (score 0):

the only known fix that I have found to this problem is to run this special command to de-quarantine the app

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Google\ Chrome\ for\ Testing.app/
```